# how to pass values from list view to an detalis Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, bundle

I have created a simple `listView` which is fetching data from server and every thing is working fine but now i want to pass the values of `listView`(Item) to another `Activity`

```
 public void onViewBind(View view, Cursor cursor, ODataRow row) {
    _list = new ArrayList<>();

     OControls.setText(view, R.id.person_name, row.getString("name"));


    // Retrive Code  dept*/
      Dep dept = new Dept(context, null);
        ODataRow rows_c = dept.select(
                new String[]{"code"}
        ).get(row.getInt("dept_id")-1);
        _list.add(rows_c.getString("code"));

        OControls.setText(view, R.id.dept_person,  rows_c.getString("code"));


    // Retrive name person*/

    ResPartner partner = new ResPartner(context, null);
    ODataRow rows = partner.select(
            new String[]{"name"}
    ).get(row.getInt("person_id")-1);

    OControls.setText(view, R.id.Type_sanction, rows.getString("name"));




}
```

i'm passing value  from the first method to the seconde usinng Array list but i want passing an object corresponding row in list view when i click

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long 
     id) {
        final Intent intent;
        intent =  new Intent(view.getContext(), Detailsdept.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)_list);

        for(int i=0; i<_list.size(); i++) {
             String x = _list.get(i);



            extras.putString("code", x);

            intent.putExtras(extras);

        }



        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "id"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: i need  to passing object not deleting

Answer (score 1):

**Create an interface in your adapter**

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
  void onItemClicked(int position, Object object);
}
```

**in your adapter call**

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(list, new Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int position, Object object) {
                  // Handle Object of list item here
            }
        });
```

**on your adapter**

```
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener; // Global scope
```

**in constructor call:**

```
this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
```

**on your item clicked event :**

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(position, _list.get(position));
    }
});
```

Comment: i'm using this adapter can i put this code in this class adapter 
https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/crm/blob/b25516b8f745cb840705f16ba5d2f47bcad897af/app/src/main/java/com/odoo/core/support/list/OCursorListAdapter.java

Comment: Yes why not. Else you can modify existing interface "IOnItemClickListener " which has public void onItemClick(View view, int position); --- You need to modify it to as public void onItemClick(View view, int position, Object obj);